# Kendo Asp.net MVC4 Click the Save Button in Grid return Data,How to return Grid page?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

**I Created Grid,this code
(index.cshtml):**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MyLayout.cshtml";}@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SeydaBenliFatura.Urunler>()
  .Name("urunGrid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(u => u.UrunAdi).Width(100).Title("Adı");
      columns.Bound(u => u.UrunAdeti).Width(100).Title("Adeti");
      columns.Bound(u => u.UrunFiyati).Width(100).Title("Fİyatı");

      columns.Command(commands =>
      {
          commands.Destroy();
      }).Width(200);
  }).ClientDetailTemplateId("template").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
  .ToolBar(toolbar =>
  {
      toolbar.Create();
      toolbar.Save();
  })

  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.InCell))
.Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
  .DataSource(dataSource =>
      dataSource.Ajax()
     .Batch(true)
        .PageSize(5)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(u => u.UrunID);
            model.Field(u => u.UrunID).Editable(true);
        })
         .Create(create => create.Action("Urunler_Create", "Urunler"))
         .Read(read => read.Action("Urunler_Read", "Urunler"))
         .Update(update => update.Action("Urunler_Update", "Urunler"))
         .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Urunler_Destroy", "Urunler")).Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
  .Pageable(pageable =>
              {
                  pageable.Refresh(true);
                  pageable.PageSizes(true);
                  pageable.PreviousNext(true);
                  pageable.Enabled(true);

              })

  .Filterable()
  .Sortable()
  .Groupable()
  )
```

This code create Grid..I am clicking Save button return this page;

{
Data:[{Faturalar: null,Musteriler: null,UrunID: 1,UrunAdi: "deneme",UrunAdeti: 12,UrunFiyati: 12,MusteriId: null}],Total: 1,AggregateResults: null,Errors: null}

There is a error here.How to return Grid page ? Normally this page go to this url :http://localhost:11018/Urunler/
But This code go to http://localhost:11018/Urunler/Urunler_Read?urunGrid-mode=insert

Comment: Please share your controller code also

Comment: Or you just check whether your read action is going as HTTP request or Ajax request.